# AUCTeX, caching document classes over an Emacs restart

Tags: auctex

The first time I create a new LaTeX document<sup>*</sup> in a new instance of Emacs AUCTeX scans my TeXLive installation to find all the available document classes .

This scanning, due to the complexity and dimensions of a typical TeXLive, takes (much less than the time I spend writing this question but nonetheless) a considerable amount of time but after that the available classes are cached and creating a second new document is instantaneous.

I wonder if it is possible to have AUCTeX cache the classes to disk, possibly with a mechanism to enforce a fresh scan of the TeXLive tree.

<sup>[*]
Strictly speaking scanning happens when I create a `document` environment but I create a `document` environment every time a create a new LaTeX document.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question! This has been bothering me for a
long time, but I never did anything about it until your question gave
me a little extra motivation.

Turns out it's pretty simple to make the cache by hand. You just need
to arrange to assign values to two variables after AUCTeX is loaded:

```
(setq LaTeX-global-class-files '("List of document classes"))
(setq TeX-global-input-files '("List of packages"))
```

(Those, of course, are placeholders: I'll explain one way to get the
correct lists below.)

So, if in your init file you have some configuration for AUCTeX, just
stick in those assignments (for example, I have a `(use-package 'latex
:ensure auctex ...)` form in my init file and I put the assignments
after `:config`). If you currently don't have any configuration for
AUCTeX, you can wrap those assignments in a `with-eval-after-load`
form, just be aware that the feature AUCTeX provides is called
`latex` (and not `auctex` or something like that), so you'd do:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'latex
  (setq LaTeX-global-class-files '("List of document classes"))
  (setq TeX-global-input-files '("List of packages")))
```

OK, so to generate the lists what I did was simply start a new LaTeX
file, insert a document environment and a package, and then use
`describe-variable` (bound to `C-h v`) to see the help for those
variables. The help buffer that pops up also includes the current
value of the variable and you can yank it from there to the proper
place in your init file (don't forget to add the single quote at the
beginning).

And, to be honest, I didn't want to clutter my init file with those
huge lists (I have 185 document classes and 2934 packages), so I put
the assignments in their own file that I load from my init file.

Comment: A more robust solution would provide an easy way to update the cache, but since I don't forsee installing new document classes or packages very often, I'll just update my cache manually.

Comment: _185 document classes and 2934 packages_  Oh yes, this is the root of the problem... Omar, tonight (Italy) I will look into the merits of your answer, for now it's just a resounding THANK YOU

Comment: @gboffi I just checked on my office computer and there I have 441 document classes and 3965 packages (which do include all the ones I have at home, according to `cl-set-difference`)!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [Omar](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2221/omar)'s [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50879/9672) I've put together an interactive
function, `dump-auctex-globals`, that writes to the standard user's
Emacs directory a (very simple) Emacs Lisp file that sets the two
global variables

```el
(defun dump-auctex-globals ()
  "Write global LaTeX class and TeX input files to auctex-globals.el."
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (expand-file-name "auctex-globals.el" user-emacs-directory)))
    (if (and (file-directory-p user-emacs-directory)
             (file-writable-p user-emacs-directory)
             LaTeX-global-class-files
             TeX-global-input-files)
        (with-temp-file filename
          (insert
           (format "(setq LaTeX-global-class-files '%S
      TeX-global-input-files '%S)"
               LaTeX-global-class-files
               TeX-global-input-files))
              nil))))
```

The function above does nothing if it is called before the two global
variables are initialized, its intended use is *after* AUCTeX has
somehow initialized them.

Another useful function is

```el
(defun clear-auctex-globals ()
  (interactive)
  (setq LaTeX-global-class-files nil)
  (setq TeX-global-input-files nil))
```

that can be evaluated when we want to force AUCTeX to parse the
TeXLive/whatever tree.

After we have cached the variables values we just need to `load-file`
their disk image

```el
(defun possibly-load-auctex-globals ()
  (let ((filename (expand-file-name "auctex-globals.el" user-emacs-directory)))
    (if (and (file-exists-p filename)
             (file-readable-p filename))
        (load-file filename))))
```

and have in our `~/.emacs` a mechanism to perform the loading.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'latex
  (possibly-load-auctex-globals))
```

Note that if the file does not exist/is not readable nothing happens...

---

Note:  I'm not sure to have written robust/elegant Emacs Lisp code (I suspect the opposite is true...) and I'm very open to your edits.

Comment: I've edited `dump-auctex-globals` a bit as requested. Please test.

Comment: @Tobias It's much nicer w/o the `prin1`, `terpri` etc, also `emacs-user-directory` is an enhancement.  You missed that the filename had an underscore when written and a dash when loaded, but I have corrected that .